# MySQL and PhpMyAdmin config.inc.php Password issue on MAMP

Tags: mysql, passwords, phpmyadmin, config, mamp

This is a very strange issue that is similar to a few other people issue that has been going on for a while with MAMP.
I recently upgraded to MAMP2 and followed the instruction for the new phpMyAdmin and it work for a while but recently whenever I try to connect to MySQL I always get this error:

```
 Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!
 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

So I changed the password to the correct one and changed all the files as per advised on this forum topic: http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11974.

But it did not work at all. I realized that there was two phpMyAdmin folder on my Mac one which is in

```
 /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/phpMyAdmin
```

and the other one in

```
 Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin
```

In the first folder the config.inc.php as the correct credential for the user, however the second  as root for both username and password. Obviously I tried to changed that but to no avail, the file is somehow always reverted to the default credential.

Did someone ever had this issue? is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this, if anyone is interested I got the fix for this (and I know many people had a similar issue). 
In mamp.pro.global.preferences.plist is listed the encoded MySQLRootPassword, if like me you did update of your MAMP overrite this password field with your old one and there you have it, it works !

Comment: where is the file mamp.pro.global.preferences.plist stored?

Comment: I have moved back to france and thus I am now back to using a laptop which runs on Win7. I think you can find it by using the searrch command. Otherwise try looking into : /Library/Application Support/living-e/MAMP PRO/, I think it was there!

Answer (score 0):

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
      Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there..